# How to format this date as a string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Here is my scenario. I am getting this date from a database:

```
11-AUG-15 10.38.00.000000000 AM
```

Is there any way to format this string to look something similar to `mm/dd/yy`?

So far I have tried the following with no luck:

- DateFormat()
- CreateODBCDate()
- LSParseDateTime()

Every time I use one of the above, I get the following error:

```
11-AUG-15 10.38.00.000000000 AM is an invalid date or time string.
```

Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `ParseDateTime`? If none of these work, that means your string is not a proper date string format and you'll have to parse it yourself before passing it in.

Comment: *I am getting this date from database* A) Which dbms ? B) What is the data type of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parseDateTime("11-AUG-15 10.38.00.000000000 AM", "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.S aa");
```

Run me: http://trycf.com/gist/aac6d63777ae1b0e9aa3/acf?theme=monokai

Then you are free to use `DateFormat()` or `DateTimeFormat()`to format the date object.

Comment: Actually, a complete answer will include a dateformat as well.

Comment: That doesn't work on *ColdFusion 9*, Henry, which is what the OP is asking for. Furthermore, format masking like that isn't even documented (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html), so is it legit?

Comment: @AdamCameron - Looks like it is documented ...albeit poorly: *...Apart from [... pop and default, the pop-conversion], parameter allows you to specify the format in which to parse the given string. Valid letters that can be used to specify the format are described [under SimpleDateFormat...]*. Though as you mentioned, it probably does not work for CF9.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this does not work with CF9.  Time to upgrade?